# CollapsingToolbarLayout: custom contentScrim similar to Facebook

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to create a custom contentScrim for my `collapsingToolbarLayout`. My collapsingToolbarLayout has an `imageview` inside. When it scrolls, in theory the imageview is suppose to fade out and my scrim color is suppose to fade in.

We all know we can create a scrim like this:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                >
```

However the android default scrim only seems to start working when you scroll 3/4 up the screen. Before you that point, the imageview is still fully shown. Also when you reach 3/4 of the screen, the scrim kicks in and automatically changes the color of the collapsingtoolbarlayout to your scrim color:

[image: scrim]

Instead of having it fill the screen fully when you scroll  3/4 of the way up and before we  reached the `toolbar`, I want it to fade gently till your scrolled up to the `toolbar`.

If you want to see an example of the effect I want to create, have a look at the Facebook app. This is the Facebook app when the collapsingToolbarLayout is fully expanded:

[image]

When you scroll to about 3/4 of the way down, the collapsingToolbarLayout has a faded blue color and the blue is not completely saturating:

[image]

So I have create the following inside my `collapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame_picture">

        <com.customshapes.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/photo"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />

        <com.customshapes.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/fading_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

The framelayout comprises of the backdrop `imageview` which holds the picture that is displayed inside my collapsingToolbarLayout and in front of it is an imageview which just holds the 'scrimColor' ?attr/colorPrimary with an alpha of 0 so that the backdrop `imageview` will shine through.

Then I implemented the appBarLayout's onOffsetChangedListener:

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

    fading_backdrop.setImageAlpha(verticalOffset);
    fading_backdrop.invalidate();
}
```

We are setting the alpha of the fading_backdrop so that it will appear when we scroll up. I'm trying to create a scrim artifically.

However, this doesn't seem to work properly. There is no fading at all when I run this code. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how I managed to create a custom scrim, which seems to be used in quite a few apps nowadays - if you look at Facebook, you will see they do not use the standard `contentScrim` for their `collapsingToolbarLayout`. The code below duplicates what Facebook does in their app.

You must set a `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` to your activity and then use the following code below to measure the size of the toolbar and the size of the appBarLayout.

When your listener is called, the `verticalOffset` actually measures the offset of the `collapsingToolbarLayout` from when it is fully expanded to the point when it touches the pinned `toolbar`. Therefore, the `verticalOffset` EXCLUDES the height of the `toolbar`. To compare apples with apples, we need to also EXCLUDE the `toolbar` height from the height of the `appBarLayout` so that when we divide the `verticalOffset` by the `totalHeight`, neither the verticalOffset nor the totalHeight contains the `toolbar` height. This is necessary in order to obtain a percentage to apply your 255 alpha value to.

```
  @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        //measuring for alpha
        int toolBarHeight = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
        int appBarHeight = appBarLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
        Float f = ((((float) appBarHeight - toolBarHeight) + verticalOffset) / ( (float) appBarHeight - toolBarHeight)) * 255;
        fading_backdrop.getBackground().setAlpha(255 - Math.round(f));
   }
```

When you scroll now, the `fading_backdrop` will gradually gain alpha when you scroll upwards so that it overlays nicely with the image in the `collapsingToolbarLayout`, similar to the facebook custom `contentScrim`.

Comment: What is fading_backgrop here?

Comment: Note, if you're using a TabLayout or a transparent status bar, you may need to add those into the calculation for `f`.